# Sort javascript array by words

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects with many layers. It looks like this:

```
var array = [
  {
    fields: { title: "Some title here" },
    sys: { id: "1234" }
  },
  {
    fields: { title: "Another one there" },
    sys: { id: "13456" }
  },
  {
    fields: { title: "Final example" },
    sys: { id: "234" }
  },
  {
    fields: { title: "Most final thing" },
    sys: { id: "4665" }
  },
];
```

Now I want to sort the array based on whether text exists in the `fields.title`. For example, I have the phrase "Final search". That needs to sort the array so the current `array[2]` and `array[3]` move to the top positions because they contain the word "final".

The sort needs to include multiple words though. So if I used the phrase "final example", `array[2]` would go first because it contains both words, followed by `array[3]` which only contains "final".

Is this possible and how?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Check out the [sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Comment: @MikeC thanks. I already knew about sort but have never seen it used like this before with multiple sort queries and on a multi level array.

Comment: It's all about how you write your compare function. That will depend a lot on your specific needs.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? I am super confused.

Comment: Js arrays are zero-indexed, so in your example you don't have array[4]. 
Also you should clarify which text you want to check (probably `fields.title`), so pls edit your question to be more concise.

Comment: @Drops thanks, I've edited the question to remedy these mistakes. Any insight into how the compare function needs to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you don't mind including [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#) in your project then you can go with something like [.sortBy()](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#sortBy).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You could split the strings by space character, count the intersection of the 2 generated arrays and use it for sorting. Another option which follows the same logic and should be faster is using regular expression and `String.prototype.match` method, something like:

```
function finder(input) {
    var reg = new RegExp(input.trim().split(' ').join('|'), 'gi');
    return function(el) {
       var m = el.fields.title.match(reg);
       return m ? m.length : -1;
    }         
}

function sortBy(arr, input) {
    var find = finder(input);
    return arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        return find(a) < find(b);
    });
}

sortBy(array, "user input");
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/sm84vk3k/)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a little more complicated than the title suggests - you're probably better of using a small text search and ranking library like Twitter's [Bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md).